# Spoil/Spoiled Vs. Indulge/Indulged

Tags: word-choice

What are the differences between *spoil/spoiled* and *indulge/indulged* as verbs and adjectives respectively?

Comment: How do you think they are the same?

Comment: As verb, both are to let others do whatever they want. As adjectives, both are to describe those who are allowed to do whatever they want.

Comment: That might be one way to say it, but it wouldn't be natural. Start from their dictionary definitions. They'll be different. Then you might want to see how they are only somewhat similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Spoiled" is a word used to indicate food that has gone bad. When used with people, it indicates not just that the person has been over-indulged, but that they have "gone bad" via such treatment.

"Indulge" just indicates that someone did something (for themself or someone else) that they didn't exactly *need* to do, but that recipient liked a lot. It does *not* imply any kind of damage to the recipient in quite the way that "spoil" does.

Answer (score 2):

MW Unabridged states that they are synonyms:

> **synonyms** *indulge*, *pamper*, *humor*, *spoil*, *baby*, and *mollycoddle* can mean, in common, to treat a person or his desires or feelings with unusual or special usually undue favor or attention.

Its discussion makes these distinctions, however:

> *indulge* implies extreme compliance and often weakness in gratifying another's wishes or desires which have little claim to fulfillment
>
> *spoil* implies a foolish or excessive indulging or pampering and throws strong stress upon its injurious effects upon the character or
>   disposition

So, to *indulge* is to *gratify*, while to *spoil* is to *pamper excessively*.

Answer (score 2):

The two words are similar in meaning, but I would say the difference is a matter of degree. To *indulge* somebody is to satisfy their wishes:

> My grandmother indulges me with chocolates.

To *spoil* is to overindulge someone such that their character is ruined (spoiled):

> Your mother-in-law really spoils the kids with all those presents.

There is a negative connotation in *spoil* that I don't think is necessarily present with *indulge*.